# How to control LED max brightness using Sphero API

Tags: python, sphero-api

I am just curious as I notice when the sphero is blinking while it is idling waiting for a connection, it is much brighter than when I set the colour using the setRGB functionality. Am I missing something to adjust the brightness as well. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: You mention that it's blinking.. are you sure it's brighter and not tricking your eyes as a result of the change in state?  LEDs are discrete, but a way to control the brightness is to change the duty cycle. ie if you want 50% brightness, have it cycle between off/on at a fixed time interval.  There shouldn't be a way to make it brighter than having it on 100% of the time.

Comment: You may be right regarding state change. So I guess a better question would be what is the difference during the "idling for connection state" and when you use the setRGB command of the sphero API as there are different visual results with respect to brightness.

Answer (score 0):

User3120784, in certain cases when you are using Sphero with the leveling system enabled, this can be seen. I personally just had an issue where the ball would do the brightness discrepancy that you are describing here, and the solution was to just check and then uncheck "Level up" in the advanced settings in the Sphero app.

To address your question in your comment, the difference is that when the Sphero is idling, it is being controlled solely by firmware, whereas the setRGB of the API is using application level code, and telling the firmware to set a brightness, which it may or may not do depending on the "Level up" setting that I mentioned earlier.